# Ordenar de mayor a menor, (30 menor que 5??!!?)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy organizando una lista de imagenes de con un numero de mayor a menor, y tengo el problema de que me pone que por ejemplo el 9 es mayor que el 30. Como puedo solucionarlo?

```
<script>

        $(function(){
            var mylist = $('#imagenes');
            var listitems = mylist.children('div').get();
            listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
               var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
               var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
               return (compA > compB) ? -1 : (compA < compB) ? 1 : 0;
            })
            $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Estás ordenando los valores,como strings, alfabéticamente. Convierte los valores a números.

Comment: he hecho lo que me decís pero me sigue pasando lo mismo :/

Comment: Hola! Recuerda poner la info adicional en la pregunta editándola, incluyendo los intentos adicionales y los resultados correspondientes. Puede haber un error oculto allí :)